# Proper way to store temporary image files for PHP

Tags: php

I have an image resource that is manipulated with `imagecopyresampled`.  I need to pass that image to a set of methods that expect a string input, not a resource.  But I don't need to store the file locally.

Is this the proper way:

1. Store the image with `imagepng` and `imagejpeg`
2. Pass string (filename) to the methods
3. Destroy the stored file with `@unlink`

Is that right?  Seems sloppy.

*Note: the image is not coming from a file upload and hence can't be accessed with `$_FILES["Filedata"]["tmp_name"]`*

Comment: Could you give more details on these methods, and what they require/ask? Bit hard to tell what you need to do otherwise.

Comment: To be honest the main question here is where do those images originate from? If they are from form uploads then the image is already stores in a temporary location so you would have no need to store the image yourself.

Comment: @Peter, they are not from form uploads. I'm pulling one image off of a CDN, cropping it, and sending the cropped version back to the CDN (Amazon S3 CDN + their classes & methods).

Comment: You can do it like now or You can send the resource data in `base64_encode`ed form - that will be string. Don't worry about the data amount, in PHP 5 the parameters are transferred just as a pointers to a memory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the Amazon S3 PHP API:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/upload_part

I assume you are using something like the `upload_part` method that takes a string `filename`. In that case, unless you plan to modify their library, you will need to store the file to disk and pass them the filename so they can read the file and perform the upload.

Besides the steps mentioned in your question you can take a look at `imagedestroy` to make sure you are freeing up the memory for your image resource after it is written to disk with `imagepng`. And then, as you stated, you can delete your temp file with `unlink` after your upload is complete.

I agree, it does seem a bit wasteful, but in this case necessary since the API doesn't seem to provide an alternative.